# Unable to change WSL 2 to WSL 1. A version number could not be parsed

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I installed WSL using the command

```
wsl --install
```

This installed default Ubuntu using WSL 2.  Now I find WSL 2 is slow for file access cross NTFS files. And I read the WSL 1 is faster for file IO when using Linux tools that needs to access NTFS files (i.e. `/mnt/g` for example, where `G:`\ is NTFS).

But I am not able to change the installed Ubuntu back to WSL 1.   Here is what I tried in PowerShell:

```
C:\Windows\system32> wsl --set-default-version Ubuntu 1
A version number could not be parsed.

C:\Windows\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2

C:\Windows\system32> wsl --set-default-version "Ubuntu" 1
A version number could not be parsed.

C:\Windows\system32> wsl --set-default-version 1
The operation completed successfully.
```

But it did not change:

```
C:\Windows\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2
```

I also rebooted the PC. I am also running all the above inside `powershell.exe` as Admin.

I am running Windows 10 Professional, version 21H1 OS build 19043.1620.

Any suggestions how to change back to WSL 1, hopefully without having to remove current Ubuntu since I spend lots of time installing Linux software on it since then?

My assumption is that one *can* change an existing install Linux from WSL 2 to WSL 1.  This is based on many reading on the net, for example from this [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/164318-how-set-linux-distribution-version-wsl-1-wsl-2-windows-10-a.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. So I can either delete my question or post the solution. I thought it might be useful to show what I did wrong as may be someone will do the same mistake and find this.

If not, I'll be happy to delete my question and answer.

My mistake was using the command

```
   wsl --set-default-version Ubuntu 1
```

It should have been this

```
   wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1
```

now it says

```
   Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
```

Now it works.

Comment: Probably worthwhile to keep it for people searching on *"A version number could not be parsed"*.  I don't see a likely duplicate, at least.