# How to run WS: and android emulator (virtualization issue)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, android, windows-subsystem-for-linux, emulator

I was running an android emulator, which demands the "intel
virtualization technology" be enabled.
I enabled it in my BIOS.
It worked well.

I tried to enable Hyper-V for running an old program. That worked, but doing so broke my emulator.
I uninstalled Hyper-V because I didn't need it any more.
Android emulator works again.

I installed Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2).
Android emulator now doesn't work

It has something to do with the intel virtualization thing,  but I don't understand it. I need to be able to use both, to develop on Linux, and test android apps.

Why can't I use both? What is going on?

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows instead of using Intel HAXM you have to configure your system for [WHPX](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-whpx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSL2 uses Hyper-V, which apparently conflicts with Android Emulator.

The solution might be to use WSL1 instead of WSL2, which doesn't
use Hyper-V.

You'll need to remove, at the least, the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature
and Hyper-V through "Turn Windows features on or off" and reboot.

Then follow the post
[Unable to change WSL 2 to WSL 1. A version number could not be parsed](https://superuser.com/questions/1716330/unable-to-change-wsl-2-to-wsl-1-a-version-number-could-not-be-parsed).

(This is all just theoretical advice which I haven't tested.)

Comment: Its been a few years since I dealt with this but I believe that the Android Emulator that is an optional component of Visual Studio has no such problems.  Not only that, in my opinion runs much faster and leaner than the one that comes with Android Studio.  I have even used it against Android Studio.  It was probably VS 2017 since I last used it but I bet it is still good.